# AWS S3 PUT Example using REST API

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-s3, put

The [AWS S3 PUT REST API docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html) are lacking a clear example of the `Authorization string` in the Request Syntax.

```
Request Syntax

PUT /Key+ HTTP/1.1
Host: Bucket.s3.amazonaws.com
x-amz-acl: ACL
Cache-Control: CacheControl
Content-Disposition: ContentDisposition
Content-Encoding: ContentEncoding
Content-Language: ContentLanguage
Content-Length: ContentLength
Content-MD5: ContentMD5
Content-Type: ContentType
Expires: Expires
x-amz-grant-full-control: GrantFullControl
x-amz-grant-read: GrantRead
x-amz-grant-read-acp: GrantReadACP
x-amz-grant-write-acp: GrantWriteACP
x-amz-server-side-encryption: ServerSideEncryption
x-amz-storage-class: StorageClass
x-amz-website-redirect-location: WebsiteRedirectLocation
x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-algorithm: SSECustomerAlgorithm
x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key: SSECustomerKey
x-amz-server-side-encryption-customer-key-MD5: SSECustomerKeyMD5
x-amz-server-side-encryption-aws-kms-key-id: SSEKMSKeyId
x-amz-server-side-encryption-context: SSEKMSEncryptionContext
x-amz-request-payer: RequestPayer
x-amz-tagging: Tagging
x-amz-object-lock-mode: ObjectLockMode
x-amz-object-lock-retain-until-date: ObjectLockRetainUntilDate
x-amz-object-lock-legal-hold: ObjectLockLegalHoldStatus

Body
```

**The docs show this request example further on...**

```
PUT /my-image.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: myBucket.s3.<Region>.amazonaws.com
Date: Wed, 12 Oct 2009 17:50:00 GMT
Authorization: authorization string
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Length: 11434
x-amz-meta-author: Janet
Expect: 100-continue
[11434 bytes of object data]
```

But again, the doc does not have an example format for Auth String. I tried `AccessKeyID` `Secret` but that didn't work. I dont' even see logical parameters in the request syntax to pass the two parts of the credential (AccessKeyID and Secret) anywhere in the examples!

Does anyone have a simple example of how to use PUT to add a .json file to S3 using the REST API? Preferrably a screenshot of PostMan setup to better explain where values go (in URL vs. as headers).

Comment: Under `URI Request Parameters`, the docs also say `The request requires the following URI parameters.` then proceeds to show ALL possible headers instead of ONLY THE REQUIRED ones. Quite confusing especially when compared to Azure's API Docs which are excellent in most cases.

Comment: Just out of interest... is there a particular reason for wanting to use the REST API rather than an AWS SDK? eg Any missing capabilities?

Comment: Hi @JohnRotenstein. I like how REST API's are stack-agnostic (don't require a certain lang). Also, because I'm using low-code solutions, there isn't a .NET/Java/Javascript/Python interface to use. Only HTTP requests.

Comment: It's explained in detail [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-header-based-auth.html) @SeaDude

Comment: Thank you for the lead @jellycsc. I still can't make head nor tails of what is required in the Authorization header. For example, if I just want to send an  `UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD` in a single chunk, what goes in the `Authorization` header?! Where do I put my AccessKeyID and secret? Its completely unclear from the docs!

Comment: @SeaDude Calm down. Implementing things in a low level can be cumbersome. It explains more about what actually goes into the `Authorization` header [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_elements.html#sigv4_elements_auth_params). If you don't want to sign your payload, then you must set `X-Amz-Content-SHA256` header AND `HashedPayload` to `UNSIGNED-PAYLOAD`. This will affect the `StringToSign` and the final calculated signature.

Comment: Thank you :) Sometimes I get worked up when I can't get a foothold on a new concept after a couple days of trying in my spare time.

Answer (score 1):

[From the AWS docs here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-examples-using-sdks.html), it appears it is **not** possible to create a PUT request to an S3 bucket using REST API alone:

```
For authenticated requests, unless you are using the AWS SDKs, you have to write code to calculate signatures that provide authentication information in your requests.
```

This is a new concept to me. I've used token requests and sending keys in headers before when authenticating via REST API's. It sounds like a more secure method of auth.

Comment: It is possible to create a PUT request via the REST API. However, all requests require authentication as described at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html 
Short summary: follow specific steps to compute the signature mentioned in your answer and add the `Authentication` header to your request.

Comment: Unfortunately, when working with things like Power Automate and Azure Logic Apps, there isn't an easy way to compute the signature (no sdk). Has anyone done this with these tools yet?